# Creating density from frequency table

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a density plot with ggplots2 from a matrix with a variable column and a count column.

```
a<-as.data.frame(matrix( c(1:10,sample(c(200:300),size=10)), ncol=2,nrow=10))
```

For a histogram I would simply use stat=identity

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=V1,y=V2))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

What I would like is to be able to use V2 values as counts to calculate the density across V1. I could normalize my data and smoothen over that, but was wondering if there is anyway to use geom_density or stat_density or something similar directly. Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First rescale your data

```
a$V2<-a$V2/sum(a$V2)
```

Then you just need tell ggplot2 that the second column is the weight of your data in the density computation

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=V1,weight=V2)) + geom_density(size=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  density(a[,1])
  density(a[,2])
  plot(density(a[,1]))
  plot(density(a[,2]))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does not help, because it is calculating the densities independently of each variable, but a[,2] represents the frequency of a[,1], so the plot I want has densities of a[,2] in y, mapped to a[,1] in x.

Comment: Ok, got your point. I'll be back with the helpful answer or a link showing the same. Thanks!